# Como fazer um grid com niveis

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Alguem saberia como, fazer um grid com dois níveis e WinForm?

exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

obrigado.

Comment: Windows Forms ou Web ? Melhore sua pergunta!

Comment: Revisado. obrigado.